# How to limit expansion in File Explorer navigation pane

Tags: windows-explorer

In Windows File Explorer some folders expand to show all of their content in the navigation pane when I click on one of their subfolders. Other folders only show the subfolder I clicked.

Here's an example. Given folders A and B. Both have 4 subfolders. If I open folder A and then click on subfolder 3, the navigation pane shows:

```
A
  3
B
```

But when I open folder B and then click on subfolder 2, navigation pane shows:

```
A
  3
B
  1
  2
  3
  4
```

Is there a way to consistently show only the open folders without expanding the navigation pane any more than necessary?

I have tried changing the Folder Options under Navigation pane with no luck.

I'm using Windows 10, but had this problem in previous versions as well.

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand your question from the description.  Can you post a picture that shows the problem?

Comment: I can't post a pic because the folders have peoples' names, but I added an example.

Comment: Create a folder structure that doesn't have confidential info in the folder names and then demonstrate the functionality you are seeing through a few pics or a video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 only expands to the current open folder while hiding all others when the number of folders in the parent location exceeds 100. There might be a registry value somewhere where you can lower this threshold. For now, you will have to populate a particular location with a certain number of dummy folders in order to reach at least 101 folder items for Windows Explorer to expand to and show only the currently open folder.

Comment: Thank you so much. I never saw the pattern before.